# How to create a for loop in C that decrements based on user input?

Tags: c, for-loop

I need to create a function which has a for loop which decrements based on what value the user has inputted. Then call this function in main.

I was going along the lines of this but unsure.. any help appreciated

```
int for_loop(int m, int k)
{
    for (int k = m; k >= 0; --k)
    {
        printf("\n%d", k);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why doesn't it work? What did you expect and what do you get?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) page soon and also visit the links describing [How to Ask a Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (MCVE). Providing the necessary details, including your MCVE, compiler warnings and associated errors, if any, will allow everyone here to help you with your question.

Comment: The `printf` function writes to `stdout`. If `stdout` is connected to an interactive terminal (and not redirected or piped) then it is *line buffered*. Line buffering means that the output written to `stdout` is stored in a buffer, until either 1) The buffer is full; Or 2) The buffer is explicitly flushed; Or 3) A newline is written. What happens when you print a leading newline is that you write the *previous* line to the terminal, while the current line will still be in the buffer. So please make it a habit to have *trailing* newlines in `printf`. I.e. `printf("%d\n", k);`

Comment: @Lundin i am asking the user what number they want to decrease the value by in the main, however i am using different variables. would i also need to put the same variables in the function? I am getting this error , declaration of 'k' hides function parameter

Comment: How many variables named `k` do you have in your function? What is the use of the *argument* variable `k`?

Comment: Please post a [mcve] including the calling code. Sounds like you have a lot of different bugs, not just one.

Comment: could you explain more what you want and what the error so we can help you

Comment: I only have one variable named k in my function. As i need to decrease, by the user input value, I should replace it with the variable they have entered from the main. Would this be correct? @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: No you have *two* variables named `k`. First the argument `k`, which is never used. Then the variable `k` defined in the loop. Those are two different and separate variables. You might want to study your beginners text-book a little more about *scope*.

Comment: Instead of `--k` You need `k-=user_entered_value` but as said the `int k` function argument is *invisible* inside the loop and needs to be renamed. It is 'shadowed' by the loop control variable `int k`.

Comment: `for (int i = m; i >= 0; i -= k)` seems to be the loop you're looking for.

Comment: Also take this as a lesson that one-letter variable names aren't that good. Use longer and descriptive variable names, which not only helps other people understand the code better but also lessen the risk of clashing variables names.

Answer (score 0):

```
int for_loop(int m, int k)
{
    int x = 0;
    for (int k1 = m; k1 >= k; k1 -= x)
    {
        if(scanf("%d", &x) != 1) x = 0;
        printf("\n%d", k1);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    for_loop(10,0);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/91e9xzcas

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't returning anything from the function then use `void` instead of int or char.

```
void for_loop(int m)`
{    for (int i = m; i >= 0; i++)
 {    
     printf("%d", i);
 }
}

int main(void) 
{    int x;
 scanf("%d", &x);
 for_loop(x);
}
```

Comment: In an answer you should at least format the code properly